# Forward Localhost to public Internet through own domain

Tags: nat, domain, ddns

Is it possible to forward IP traffic to my domain to a server on my LAN?

For example HTTP traffic to data.mydomain.com to 192.168.x.x:8989?

Comment: That's kinda how the whole web works... What software specifically is running on port 8989 there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  If your asking how to access your server from outside your intranet, you are going to have to provide some more details, because that doing so is both trivial and dependent on the configuration of your network.  Can it be done, that is how the entire internet works, but if you are able to make the required changes is something only you can tell us.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can forward internet requests to "data.mydomain.com" to a host on your local network using a port forwarding configuration on the router connecting your local network.  To do this you will need:

1. access to the DNS settings of your domain in order to configure the mapping from domain name "data.mydomain.com" to the WAN IP address of your home router. Often the WAN address is dynamic (changes over time) in which case you will also need a dynamic DNS solution to overcome.  Dynamic DNS is typically an agent on your router telling the DNS service of "data.mydomain.com" what your WAN IP address is whenever the router gets a new IP address.
2. port forwarding configuration on your local router  e.g. port (80 HTTP) forwards to 192.168.1.4:8989 on your LAN, plus any others e.g. HTTPS, SSH etc.  Each must have its own port to port mapping, or you can set DNZ to point everything "unknown" to a single host.
3. IP assignment on your target host should be determinate (e.g. 192.168.1.4), either statically assigned or consistently served by DHCP by your router.

Comment: Point 2: Its DMZ: DeMilitarized Zone, but using DMZ is strongly discouraged. It basically opens your entire server up to the internet, and hackers love that. Only for testing purposes should it be used, and even then it is better to test using different methods. Given the core of the answer is correct in all other details, +1 from me anyways.